# How to replace regex string with '\'

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to include the '\' character in the regex replacement. For example:

```
E{bla}      -> \bla
```

The statement I use (in ruby) is

```
text.gsub!(/\\E{(\w*)}/, '\\\1')
```

but I get

```
E{bla}      -> \1
```

instead. How do I get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need 6 backslashes like this:

```
text.gsub!(/\\E{(\w*)}/, '\\\\\1')
```

The `\\\\\\1` gets passed to gsub as `\\\1` (the 1st, 3rd and 5th backslashes each escape the following backslash). This is interpreted by the regexp engine as `\` followed by `\1` (the first backslash escapes the second backslash)